# Can a C++ macro count the cases in a switch statement?

Tags: c++, algorithm, macros, c-preprocessor

I have many different lambdas that all iterate through a list of parameters and pick some of them (with a switch) to do an operation on.  I want to make sure that each lambda finds at least one of each case it is looking for and to report back if any case isn't hit.  I can setup a vector of bools to track if each case was found, but I need to know the full count of cases in the switch to see if I got them all and to see the indices of the bools.  I'd *really* like to integrate it in the general case macro, that way nothing will break if a case gets added later without updating a count.

Lambda example:

```
#define OneCase ???

auto MysteryLambda = [](Parameters params) -> int
{
 //something to set the case count to 0, whatever it is

 for (auto param : params)
 {
  switch (param)
  {
   case First:
    OneCase; //case count + 1
    //do operation
    break;
   case Second:
    OneCase; //case count + 1
    //do operation
    break;
   case Third:
    OneCase; //case count + 1
    //do operation
    break;
  }
 }


 static const int cases = ???; //this would be 3

 std::cout << "The enum has " << cases << " cases." << std::endl;

 return cases;
};
```

Then the lambda can return that const count.  Is this possible?

If it isn't possible, is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, maybe if you explain the context in which you want to use this and how it might help.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I want an automatic way to count the cases in a switch just by placing some command in each case.

Comment: Do you want this because you want to statically enforce that every lambda has a `case` for every value of the `enum`?

Comment: Count all of the cases, not those that are evaluated? Think what that means... you are asking without computing the value to come up with a result is it not?

Comment: @j_random_hacker No, that's the problem, each lambda only looks at a subset of the possible cases, but I still want to know if it didn't fill out everything it is looking at.

Comment: Now, if you want a different approach... consider using a variadic template instead of the switch. It will be a fun exercise (although I would advice against the complexity)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Well I was hoping that macros had some trick to hold at least a single int in an internal state, but I guess that's not really viable.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Haha, I'm trying to make this easier to maintain, not harder!

Comment: So you have a collection of lambdas, and an `enum` type, and you want to know, for each value `x` of the `enum`, whether at least one lambda has a `case` for `x`?

Comment: @j_random_hacker No, that's not what I want to count.  Say a lambda has cases for First and Third only, I want to know that the lambda has 2 cases in its switch statement.  Then I'd want to set index 0 of a vector of bools to true if I process the first case, index 1 for the second case.  Then my lambda would return the count of 2 cases, so I can loop through the first 2 entries in the vector and confirm they are true.

Comment: @user173342: Really, you should add a usage example with what you expect out of this. It is not clear whether you want what j_random_hacker mentions, or if each lambda uses a different enum, whether you want to detect *which* lambda did not match all branches, or just whether any of the cases was not handled anywhere...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas "just whether any of the cases was not handled anywhere", that's it.  Sorry if my explanation has been terrible.  It's probably a bad idea in the first place, but I got curious if it was viable.

Comment: OK, I *think* I've got it.  Inside *each* lambda, after looping through all the parameters, you want to see if there were any `case` statements *in that lambda* that didn't fire.  Correct?  Because this is easy to do with a macro.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yep!  I think I've got a solution using \_\_COUNTER\_\_, but this really feels awkward.  You've got a better way?

Comment: I think so, writing it up now :)

Comment: Actually...  That idea hit a wall.  I've got another idea, but it's not nearly as pretty. :(

Comment: @j_random_hacker Ok, I'll post my own crappy solution as an answer too, just to be complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea: Turn a `switch` into a bunch of `if` statements that record their presence in an array.

Preamble:

```
#define BIG_ENOUGH 50     // Just needs to be bigger than the maximum enum value

#define BEGIN_DETECTED_SWITCH(x) \
{ \
    vector<bool> __has(BIG_ENOUGH, false); \
    vector<bool> __saw(BIG_ENOUGH, false); \
    auto __x(x); \
    { ;    // Dummy open brace to be consumed by first DETECTED_CASE()

#define END_DETECTED_SWITCH \
    } \
    for (int i = 0; i < BIG_ENOUGH; ++i) { \
        if (__has[i] && !__saw[i]) { \
            cout << "Didn't see any " << i << "'s!\n"; \
        } \
    } \
}

#define DETECTED_CASE(x) \
    } \
    __has[x] = true; \
    if (__x == (x)) { \
        __saw[x] = true;
```

Now turn each `switch` statement into:

```
BEGIN_DETECTED_SWITCH(someEnumVal)
    DETECTED_CASE(First)
        // Code for first
    DETECTED_CASE(Second)
        // Code for second
    DETECTED_CASE(Third)
        // Code for Third
END_DETECTED_SWITCH
```

You could slightly generalise it by having `END_DETECTED_SWITCH` take a lambda parameter that gets called with every non-firing `case`, instead of hardcoding the "reaction".

Comment: Since the amount of cases would be small, there wouldn't be much of an issue with having lots of if statements.  This could be done without macros at all, right?  Certainly less insane than what I've been pursuing

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of macros entirely, unless you want to rely on programmer discipline to ensure that `__has[x]` and `__saw[x]` always get set at the right times.  And it's still fairly insane :-P

Comment: However, it has one big advantage over counting (besides counting being compiler dependent): it's possible to have the vector store a `std::pair<bool, std::string>` and have the macro place the enum text as a string in `__has`.  I don't really see a way to slip such functionality into the `__COUNTER__` method. edit: Nevermind, it'd be possible but not pretty

Comment: Good idea.  Also the `__COUNTER__` approach is vulnerable if other code calls `__COUNTER__` somewhere inside the `switch`.  That's probably unlikely, but debugging versions of various things might do this behind the scenes.

Comment: This is not a very good idea because it looks a lot like a regular switch/case statement but doesn't have the same semantics (break, fall through, and so on).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: `break;` and (explicit) fall-through can be handled correctly by adding flag variables `int __b = 0, __f = 0;` and changing each `if (__x == (x)) {` to `while ((__x == (x) || __f) && !__b++) { __f = 0;`.  Then `#define FALL_THROUGH __f = 1; __b = 0; break;`.  Implicit fall-through seems hard to emulate, but in any case that is nowadays considered a misfeature (witness its removal from modern languages like C#).

Answer (score 2):

It would be just this side of possible to use the GCC/MSVC `__COUNTER__` macro for this, though it would entail a significant amount of scaffolding around the switch statement itself. In general, no, it's not possible. It sounds like you want a `map` of lambdas, not a switch statement.

Comment: It really doesn't take much scaffolding, and it's only done once.  This actually works and is basically what I was looking for, although I'm sad that something hacky like \_\_COUNTER\_\_ is the only way to do it.  Oh well, check out my answer to see the terrible results of your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Sneftel's __COUNTER__ suggestion is viable!  Here's how I managed to make it work:

```
enum class Parameter //sample parameters, they don't have to be the same for each lambda
{
 First, Second, Third, Fourth
};

typedef std::vector<Parameter> Parameters;

void test()
{
 static const int startcases = __COUNTER__ + 1; //the initial state of counter when this lambda is pre-proced

 auto GetIndex = [](unsigned int counter) -> unsigned int //helper function, it takes __COUNTER__ from wherever it is called
 {
  return counter - startcases;
 };

 //Example lambda.  This isn't built to do anything useful at all.

 auto Example = [&GetIndex](Parameters parameters, std::vector<bool>& used) -> unsigned int
 {
  for (auto parameter : parameters)
  {
   switch (parameter) //only looking at First and Third
   {
   case Parameter::First:
    used[GetIndex(__COUNTER__)] = true;
    break;
   case Parameter::Third:
    used[GetIndex(__COUNTER__)] = true;
    break;
   }
  }

  static const unsigned int cases = __COUNTER__ - startcases; //this would be 2

  std::cout << "The enum has " << cases << " cases." << std::endl;

  return cases;
 };

 //Ok, time for a test!

 //Load out sample params, using VC++2012 so no init list on vectors. :(

 Parameters parameters; 
 parameters.push_back(Parameter::First);
 parameters.push_back(Parameter::Second);
 parameters.push_back(Parameter::First); //no Third in this vector
 parameters.push_back(Parameter::Fourth);

 std::vector<bool> used; //a vector of bools filled to some arbitrary capacity with falses, I can have size checks in a more extensive helper function so no big deal
 used.insert(used.begin(), 10, false);

 unsigned int cases = Example(parameters, used); //returns # of cases in this particular lambda

 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cases; ++i) //loop through for each case and see if one is false (meaning it had no hit)
 {
  if (!used[i])
  {
   std::cerr << "Didn't process case " << i << "." << std::endl; 
  }
 }
}
```

Output:

```
The enum has 2 cases.
Didn't process case 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of lines of code per case is fixed (admittedly a hard constraint), the answer is yes !

Insert `Begin= __LINE__;` before the switch and `End= __LINE__;` after it. Anytime later, `(End - Begin - Extra) / LinesPerCase` gives you the answer :)